# How do I get nodes from the specific edge in the networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to compare nodes of different edges in the graph. How can I get the nodes(n1 and n2) from the edge(n1,n2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An edge in [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html) is defined by its nodes, so I'm not really sure what you're asking here. A specific edge in the graph is just a tuple of nodes, with an optional weighting.

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(1,2)
g.add_edge(2,3)
g.edges()
```

gives

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

As you can see, the list of edges explicitly provides the nodes of each edge.

**Update:** Does this do what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import networkx as nx
import random

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(1,4),(2,5)])

random_edge = random.choice(g.edges())

print 'Randomly selected edge is:', random_edge
print 'Nodes are', random_edge[0], 'and', random_edge[1]
```

Comment: suppose I have an edge list, one of them might be edge(2,3) which is the edge between node 2 and 3. I want the program, randomly give me an edge from my data, and also give me it's nodes, like here gives me 2 and 3.

Comment: yes, thanks. Actually this is first part of my program, I need to work with these nodes later on. So I was thinking there might be a function to get_nodes, the reverse of the function get_edge... But it is still good enough!

Comment: this doesn't really make sense.  A network edge 'node' is an object instance or "view" (from what I've been able to gather from the docs) with a battery of attributes and other OO-paraphernalia.  A 'node label', on the other hand, is the 'name' of the node, but not the networkx object instance.  How does one get the networkx object instance or `view` associated with the node label contained in a networkx edge's data from an edge?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to what I **think** was the **intended** question is:

```
graph = networkx.read_graphml('some_fully_loaded_graph.graphml')
edge0 = list(graph.edges(data=True))[0]

subgraph = graph.edge_subgraph([edge0[:2]])
nodes0 = list(subgraph.nodes(data=True))
```